# Web Client Slow Download Video?

Tags: c#, performance, download, webclient

I use webclient download to youtube, i have an 100 mb connection but my mp4 download rate 100kb/s :)

```
WebClient client = New WebClient;
  client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 6.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
  client.Proxy = Null;
  client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri(url.ToString()), directory + file.ToString());
```

How to fix this problem or where my wrong?
I think youtube block my speed but i tried Internet download manager then very fast down this video.
Thanks for help!
Sorry for my bad English.

Ertim Abon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing inherently wrong with your code - the "problem" is on the other end. YouTube throttles the connection so that the video is downloaded at about the same speed as it's played. This saves on bandwidth if (when!) people don't watch the entire video. Well-configured video streaming websites will give you a burst at the start and then stream the rest at a lower speed.

The only way around it would be to see if you could make multiple requests to different parts of the video to get the "burst" multiple times, for instance with `Range` headers. They might not like you doing that though.

Comment: Thank you for help Internet Download Manager how to fix this problem? Her download very quickly.

Comment: Can't really say how a specific program I've never used does it, I guess you could try looking at its behavior with a packet sniffer to see how it gets around the throttling

Comment: If i changing my IP address fix this problem? Her blocking my IP?

Comment: Probably not. That's what they do for all users. And it's a sensible thing to do, probably saves them loads on bandwidth bills.